# regex for removing '-1' from a text file

Tags: java, regex

i want to remove -1 from my text file using regex. 
i have tried this expression `("-?+[1]", "")`. but as there are (1) positive one in the file,i don't want to remove 1. this expression remove all the ones from the file. i am new to regex. can any one help me out ?

---

my text file look like this :

```
2 -1 11 -1
1 -1 11 -1
11 -1 1 -1
11 -1 1 -1 1 -1
11 -1 2 -1 1 -1
11 -1 1 -1 2 -1
11 -1 3 -1 1 -1
11 -1 1 -1 3 -1....
```

Comment: why don´t you just use [String#replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)). There is no real need for regex.

Comment: `-?+` this would actually make the minus character optional, see here for more info (and stuff to learn about): http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html

Comment: @KevinEsche `String#replace` uses regular expressions, it's just not a very sophisticated one that is needed here :)

Comment: @Thomas Does it? I allways thought that `String#replaceAll` and `String#replaceFirst` were the only replace methods using regex.

Comment: @Thomas: Internally, yes. But it is easier to avoid mistakes in these simple cases if you use `replace()`.

Comment: @KevinEsche and @Keppil you're right :) I'm using `replaceAll()` in most cases so I totally forgot there was a difference in the api. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What if there is `-10` in the input? Do we want to change that to `0`? Or can you exclude this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the space after a `-1` (which only exists if `-1` is not at the end of a line, it seems), and in case you want to safeguard against accidentally changing `-10` to `0`, you could use a regex, replacing

```
-1\b ?
```

with the empty string.

**Explanation:**

```
-1   # matches -1
\b   # ensures that the number ends here
[ ]? # matches an optional space character
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wY2xV7/1).

Note that you need to escape the backslash in Java:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("-1\\b ?", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression for -1, is, simply `-1`. Use that as the argument.

(Regular expressions are based around string literals with wildcard-style embellishments.)

Answer (score 0):

Following trick will do the job...

`stringObj.replaceAll("-1", "")`

Yes, look ahead or behind won't do the job.

Comment: @Keppil... yes! corrected. Thanks for pointing out mistake. :(